# Rails: Return only objects where all associations meet a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Setup:  Rails 3.2.18, Postgres

I have two objects, for sake of example, call them `Author` and `Article`, with the following setup:

```
class Author
  has_many :articles

  ...
end

class Article
  belongs_to :author

  class << self

    def published_over_one_year_ago
      where(arel_table[:published_at].lt(1.year.ago))
    end

  end
end
```

I'm trying to find all `Author` records where *all* associated `Article` records are published over one year ago.  This code:

```
Author.joins(:article).merge(Article.published_over_one_year_ago)
```

... returns `Author` objects where *at least one* associated `Article` is published over one year ago, but I need *only* `Author` records where *all* associated `Article` records are over one year old.  Is this possible with arel / ActiveRecord, or do I have to use raw SQL?

Potentially "Working" SQL Solution:

```
query = ERB.new(<<-SQL_END).result(binding)
  'author'.id in (
    select art.author_id
    from articles art
    group by art.author_id
    having sum(case (art.published_at::date >= current_date) when true then 1 else 0 end) = 0 AND
      sum(case(art.published_at::date < current_date) when true then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  )
SQL_END


# The following now appears to do what I want it to do.
Author.includes(:articles).where(query)
```

**UPDATE** I see there's already a suggested answer using arel, which is outstanding. Anyone have a suggestion for using straight ActiveRecord, if possible?

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a raw SQL solution in mind?

Comment: Yeah, it actually appears to work.  See edit.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using Arel and a Common Table Expression :

```
articles = Article.arel_table
authors = Author.arel_table
cte_table = Arel::Table.new(:cte_table)
composed_cte =
     Arel::Nodes::As.new(cte_table,
                         articles.project(articles[:author_id],
                                          articles[:published_at].maximum.as("max_published_at"))
                                 .group(articles[:author_id])
                        )
```

Then :

```
authors
  .join(cte_table).on(cte_table[:author_id].eq(authors[:id]))
  .with(composed_cte)
  .where(cte_table[:max_published_at].lt(1.year.ago))
  .project(authors[:id])
  .to_sql
```

returns (formatted for clarity):

```sql
WITH "cte_table" AS (
    SELECT articles.author_id,
           MAX(articles.published_at) AS max_published_at
    FROM articles
    GROUP BY articles.author_id
)
SELECT authors.id
FROM authors
INNER JOIN cte_table
ON cte_table.author_id = authors.id
WHERE cte_tble.max_published_at < '2014-01-25 23:04:16.532796'
```

---

Using it :

From

```
[2] test»  Article.pluck(:author_id, :published_at)                                                                                                                                    
D, [2015-01-26T00:10:06.763197 #21897] DEBUG -- :    (0.6ms)  SELECT "articles"."author_id", "articles"."published_at" FROM "articles"
=> [
  [0] [
    [0] 1,
    [1] Sun, 25 Jan 2015 23:31:58 UTC +00:00
  ],
  [1] [
    [0] 1,
    [1] Fri, 01 Jan 1999 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
  ],
  [2] [
    [0] 2,
    [1] Fri, 01 Jan 1999 00:00:00 UTC +00:00
  ]
```

The query returns :

```
[2015-01-26T00:10:25.279587 #21897] DEBUG -- :    (0.9ms)  WITH "cte_table" AS (SELECT "articles"."author_id", MAX("articles"."published_at") AS max_published_at FROM "articles" GROUP BY "articles"."author_id") SELECT "authors"."id" FROM "authors" INNER JOIN "cte_table" ON "cte_table"."author_id" = "authors"."id" WHERE "cte_table"."max_published_at" < '2014-01-25 23:10:25.277902'
=> [
  [0] {
    "id" => "2"
  }
]
```

---

**EDIT**

Without using Arel :

```
Author.joins(:articles)
      .where("authors.id != ANY (?)",
              Article.select('author_id')
                     .where("published_at > ?", 1.year.ago)
             )
```

If you add `.published_last_year` to Article :

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author

  def self.published_last_year
    where("published_at > ?", 1.year.ago)
  end  
end
```

Then

```
Author.joins(:articles)
      .where("authors.id != ANY (?)",
              Article.published_last_year.select('author_id'))
```

---

**Rails4 version**

```
 Author.joins(:articles)
       .where.not(id: Article.published_last_year.select('author_id'))
```

Comment: Glorious answer.  Any tricks up your sleeve for a pure ActiveRecord answer?

Comment: @CDub : Edited my answer. Not really pure AR, but I don't of any way to express `NOT ANY` in AR3.